# How do I add one file's XML content to another XML file quickly (performance)?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have 2 XML file. One is the main XML file and one is the additional XML file. These file has a specific format like the example below.

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nation xmlns="http://abc.def.ghi">
  <library>
    <book>
      <title name="Alice in Wonderland"/>
      <authors>
        <author order="1" name="Alex, A."/>
        <author order="2" name="Bob, B."/>
        <author order="3" name="Carrot, C."/>
      </authors>
      <notes>
       <note description='Secret ID: 123456'/>
      </notes>
    </book>
    <novel>
      <title name="Bob in Wonderland"/>
      <authors>
        <author order="1" name="Zen, Z."/>
      </authors>
      <notes>
       <note description='Secret ID: 123457'/>
      </notes>
    </novel>
  </library>
</nation>
```

additional.xml:

```
<additionalAutors>
  <authorList description='Secret ID: 123456'>
    <author order="4" name="Den, D."/>
    <author order="5" name="East, E."/>
  </authorList>
  <authorList description='Secret ID: 123457'>
    <author order="2" name="Fan, F."/>
  </authorList>
</additionalAutors>
```

Note: there can be many books and novels. There can be more things other than books and novels, like newspapers, dictionaries...etc

I want to add the information contained in the additional XML file into the main XML file so it becomes like below:

result.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nation xmlns="http://abc.def.ghi">
  <library>
    <book>
      <title name="Alice in Wonderland"/>
      <authors>
        <author order="1" name="Alex, A."/>
        <author order="2" name="Bob, B."/>
        <author order="3" name="Carrot, C."/>
        <author order="4" name="Den, D."/>
        <author order="5" name="East, E."/>
      </authors>
      <notes>
       <note description='Secret ID: 123456'/>
      </notes>
    </book>
    <novel>
      <title name="Bob in Wonderland"/>
      <authors>
        <author order="1" name="Zen, Z."/>
        <author order="2" name="Fan, F."/>
      </authors>
      <notes>
       <note description='Secret ID: 123457'/>
      </notes>
    </novel>
  </library>
</nation>
```

Note: the logic is to add author with same Secret ID from the additional file to the main file:

**I need to do it fast because there are performance requirement.** I'm using XSLT to do the job. How should my xsl file (let's call it solution.xsl) look like if all these files are in the same directory?

I want to be able to run the following line on my Mac if all the files mentioned are in the same folder:

`xsltproc -o new_main.xml solution.xsl main.xml`

Here is my code. It's really far from finish and does not make much sense yet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

  <template match="@*|node()">
    <copy>
      <apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </copy>
  </template>

  <template match="library">
    <copy>
      <apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <for-each select="document('additional.xml')/library/book">
        <copy>
          <apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </copy>
      </for-each>
    </copy>
  </template>

</stylesheet>
```

If possible, please provide an answer that is written in XSLT version 1 because i'm using xsltproc on a Mac.

Comment: Did you try anything?? If tried please share.

Comment: Please see the update for my code (if you are still interested)

Comment: ! If you see carefully there is not library element inside additional.xml which you use in for-each iteration.

Comment: Yes, that was my old code. An ideal code should not depend on library or book. I tried your code and it does what I want. But I have issue removing the xmlns, do you know how to remove them? exclude-result-prefixes doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://abc.def.ghi"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://abc.def.ghi"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs #default"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:variable name="additional" select="document('additional.xml')" as="node()"/>

    <xsl:template match="authors">
        <authors>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <xsl:variable name="aut-name" select="following-sibling::notes[1]/note/@description"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$additional/descendant::*[name() = 'author' and parent::*[name() = 'authorList']/@description = $aut-name]">
                <xsl:sort select="@order"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </authors>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: To use your code, I had to remove xmlns="http://abc.def.ghi" in my main.xml file to make it work. I am not allowed to change this file, but I can change the additional.xml file. Do you have any suggestion on how to make it work and not add any xmlns attribute?

Comment: Are you strict to use 1.0? if you use 2.0 you can avoid removing default namespace by using 'xpath-default-namespace="http://abc.def.ghi"'.

Comment: I'm happy to use 2.0 if I can use it for free commercially for both Mac and Linux. Do you know if we have such options? I don't really know one that does that yet. xsltproc on Mac only support 1.0

Comment: Thank you Amrendra, I am able to come up with a solution that truly solves my problem, after learning your code, I have posted the solution in my question post.

Answer (score 0):

> *This was originally added to the question by the OP and has been moved here.*

I found the solution, but to use it I will have to modify my additional.xml file (and I'm fine with editing it):

additional.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<additionalAutors xmlns="http://add.authors.com">
  <authorList description='Secret ID: 123456'>
    <author order="4" name="Den, D."/>
    <author order="5" name="East, E."/>
  </authorList>
  <authorList description='Secret ID: 123457'>
    <author order="2" name="Fan, F."/>
  </authorList>
</additionalAutors>
```

And after learning Amrendra Kumar's code, I am able to come up with the solution that truly solves my problem:

solution.xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:abc="http://abc.def.ghi"
  xmlns:add="http://add.authors.com"
  exclude-result-prefixes="abc add"
  version="1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:variable name="additional" select="document('additional.xml')" as="node()"/>

    <xsl:template match="abc:authors">
        <authors xmlns="http://abc.def.ghi">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="abc:author"/>
            <xsl:variable name="aut-name" select="following-sibling::abc:notes[1]/abc:note/@description"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$additional/descendant::*[name() = 'author' and parent::*[name() = 'authorList']/@description = $aut-name]">
                <xsl:sort select="@order"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </authors>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="add:author">
      <xsl:element name="author" use-attribute-sets="order" namespace="http://abc.def.ghi">
        <xsl:attribute name = "order">
          <xsl:value-of select = "@order"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name = "name">
          <xsl:value-of select = "@name"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```